# What is the story behind Karna and the Two golden Mountains?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, arjuna, karna

- There is story in other sites and many people say this story of Karna and the **two golden mountains**
- This story is about Karna and Arjuna giving **dana** of the two golden mountains and the story concept **varies** with many **sites** and many people.

**QUESTION :**

- What is the **real story** behind Karna and the two golden mountains ?

<sup>Please give the answer from a trusted site</sup>.

Comment: All the sites I have seen have almost the same story friend. These maybe added in the regional translations of MB.

Comment: @SreeCharan friend what is MB

Comment: Mahabharata friend.See [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/234/explain-abbreviations-used-by-users-briefly/236#236) post for all the short forms used on this site.

Comment: Lol. Sakthi you don't even know what MB (Mahabharata) is? It's the epic in which Karna is just a character.